# How to send newline commands over Websocket message?

Tags: html, reactjs, websocket, fastapi

**Setup**

- Python FastApi backend server
- JS React frontend client
- react-use-websocket for frontend ws client

**Issue**

So I need to send some messages from backend API to frontend client over Websocket connections and display these messages to user. However I don't know how to escape to a new line while displaying these messages. I tried sending \n inside the Websocket message. JS doesn't display this \n character but neither does switch to a newline. It just ignores it. Also tried sending some whitespace but that didn't help either. It just shows a single space regardless of how many whitespaces I left at the API side.

**Code**

> note: TextTransition component is from react-text-transition but the
> behavior is same with a standart html paragraph.

```
const {lastJsonMessage} = useWebSocket(socketURL);

//...

return (
    <div>
    ...
        ...
        <div style={boxStyle}>
            <h1 style={{cursor: "default"}}>Message</h1>
            <p style={{cursor: "default"}}>━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━</p>
            <TextTransition
                text={lastJsonMessage ? lastJsonMessage.message : ""}
                style={{cursor: "default"}}
                springConfig={ presets.stiff }
            />
        </div>
        ...
    ...
    </div>
)
```

*What can and should I do? Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

`\n` does not cause a new line in HTML. You will either need to send `<br/>` instead, or replace `\n` on the client side with that, for instance:

```
<TextTransition
  text={lastJsonMessage ? lastJsonMessage.message.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>') : ""}
  style={{cursor: "default"}}
  springConfig={ presets.stiff }
  />
```

This assumes that `TextTransition` accepts HTML (not just text). If the latter then you may be out of luck, because that component just won't let you set control characters in your text.

Comment: I have tried sending an <br/> tag as well. Unfortunately it doesn't recognize it. Not just TextTransition component, even an <p></p> paragraph displays it like "....<br/>....".

Comment: if a `p` tag instead of `TextTransition` is an option for you then you can get this to work using https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml.